# Convert decimal to hours and minutes

Tags: vba, report, reporting

I am logging the number of hours worked on a project in 2 columns - hours and minutes.

Could be -

```
1.00
1.15
1.30
1.45
```

etc.

When I have the time logs -

```
6.30
1.30
1.00
1.45
```

The total is 10.75, whereas I need the total to be 10.45.

So far, I have the VB expression -

```
=Sum(Fields!Hours.Value, "DataSet1") + (Sum(Fields!Minutes.Value, "DataSet1") / 60)
```

This is to be shown in a RDLC report.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: total for the second column is 10.05 actually and I don't really understand what differs the first column from the second? Can you put more effort into showing an actual example as it's hard to understand where your numbers come from?

Comment: First column is hours and the second column is minutes. When the log is added by a user, they select a hour (1 - 8) and then a minute(0, 15, 30, 45). In the report, it shows a total of 10.75.

Comment: If you are using Sql Server 2008 or above you can use time datatype for the column that will give you correct sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the decimal part as minutes, but there are 100 parts of one whole, not 60 as there are 60 minutes in an hour.

To do calculations on the numbers you need to convert the hour.minute format into fractional hours, e.g. 1.30 would be converted 1.5 hours.

That can be done using a formula like this (where `time` is the value to convert):

```
Int(time) + 100.0 * (time Mod 1.0) / 60.0
```

After the calculation, if you want the result in hour.minute format, you need to convert it back:

```
Int(time) + Round(60.0 * (time Mod 1.0) / 100.0, 2)
```